# How to be good at analysing texts

Tags: text-analysis

I always have problems in analyzing texts, as I'm not sure what analyzing actually entails. What does it mean to have a good analysis of an author's work, either fictional or non - fictional?

Answer (score 2):

There are many angles to take when analyzing fiction and you should focus on the one that interests you the most.

**Why?**

> Answer: Because then you'll write a more interesting analysis if you
>   do.

What Are Possible Angles?

1. Plot
2. Character
3. Voice / Style

The definitive guide to learning about writing and analyzing them from these various angles is the fantastic book by the late author, [Gary Provost, Make Your Words Work -- Amazon link](http://amzn.to/2qEWv3K).

**Keep Analysis Excerpts Short**

I also tend to like to keep the excerpt I'm analzying short for two reasons:

1. you can get a very good idea of the author's work in just a few paragraphs
2. analyzing an entire book could be quite overwhelming

For my book, [Fiction Writing Gems - Free to read at amazon for Kindle OLL program](http://amzn.to/2pYkmiE), I analyze the beginnings of 26 published novels.

One of my favorites to analzye was the novel, [TailSpin by Catherine Coulter](http://amzn.to/2pwUPvm).

Here's just a snippet of novel to show why it was so much fun to analyze:

> Black Rock Lake
>   Oranack, Maryland
>
> Friday night
>
> She thought she swallowed because her throat burned hot, as if
>   splashed with sharp acid, but she wasn't sure because she couldn't
>   think clearly. Her mind felt dark, heavy and thick as chains, and she
>   knew to her soul there was violence just beyond it.

**Here's an excerpt of my sample analysis:**

> **More About the Mystery Protagonist Technique**
>
> Many authors employing the Mystery Protagonist technique are
>   attempting to set up tension as a hook to the reader by enticing the
>   reader to find out who the action is happening to.
>
> Coulter's attempt fails, because her author's camera falls upon the
>   wrong details. She describes the wrong things.
>
> **Describing the Wrong Things**
>
> What are the wrong things and why are they wrong? She thought she
>   swallowed -- generally if you are thinking at all, then you know if
>   you swallowed. The author's attempt to show the character's
>   disorientation fails and jars me from my reading, and I am only four
>   words into the beginning of her story. Plus, remember, as I read I am
>   living vicariously as the viewpoint character which means that I don't
>   know what I am swallowing. That makes me ignorant or somewhat stupid.
>   Why would I want to associate myself with a stupid character and live
>   vicariously as if I am them?

**Value of Short Analysis**

The value of this type of analysis on very short excerpts is that it gives you a quick way to learn what type of writing works and what type doesn't and why.